# How to add reference to calendar in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I have received mails in Gmail which have reference to a date. As you can see in the picture with mouse hover, the add to calendar balloon appears.

[image: screen shot]

The question is: **how could I make this type of references to calendar?**

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? That's a feature of Gmail in that if it sees something that looks like a date it offers the user a way to add to their Google Calendar without having to switch out. For other people to get that option in Gmail with messages from you, just include something that can be interpreted as a date. If that's not what you're after, please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: I think the sender is using some features of gmail that making the date being referenced. There is not such a feature when I rewriting the email content and sending it to myself.

Comment: No, that's not true. See: [Add events to Google Calendar from Gmail](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2013/05/add-events-to-google-calendar-from-gmail.html). It probably doesn't work when you send messages to yourself because, well, why would it need to? It's you. Try to get a friend to send you a message with that sort of text.

Comment: I have tried it too, but there is no "add to calendar" feature.

Comment: Maybe it hasn't been rolled out to your country.

Comment: The photo is an email from who is in my countary too.

Comment: @AlE. can you try this in your gmail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires no special formatting. It's Gmail using its natural language processing to find things that look like they could be a date.

I used a different email address to send myself the following message:

> Let's get together on Tuesday.
>
> Otherwise, let's shoot for the 15th.

I didn't use any special formatting. When I opened the message in Gmail with my regular account, this is what I got:

[image: Gmail received]

If you look close, "on Tuesday" has a dashed line under it. When I mouseover:

[image: on mouseover]

And then, when I click:

[image: after a click]

So there's no special formatting which needs to be done by the sender.

Comment: I also have asked sending email from other peoples but the word processing unit wasn't operate correctly. Being a date assigned to the weekday name make me believed the sender is using some gadget or ... . I was looking for the answer to use this feature in my emails to set appointments on other months or weeks. In the question I didn't mentioned that it just happens when I'm sending email to myself. So, please modify your last sentence and I will accept your answer.